# Is a different version of tsc used when using npm run?

Tags: typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-run

I have VS Code and a Node.js project using Typescript. In my package.json `script` block there is an item:

```
"build-ts": "tsc"
```

If I run plain `tsc` on the integrated terminal command line, the compilation is fine. But if I invoke `npm run build-ts`, it detects syntax errors on one file. The cause of the error seems to be from an older compiler version.

If I run `tsc -v` on the command line, it shows Version 2.9.2. Does `npm run` use another version of tsc somewhere?

By the way, is `npm run` from the package [npm-run-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)? I ran an `npm list` and I could not find npm-run-script locally or globally.

Comment: Do you have `tsc` installed locally, in `node_modules` folder of a project? Seems that `npm run` looks here first.

Comment: That was it! There was one version as a dev dependency. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was solved by comment, yet I'll leave this answer here as a bit more verbose version.

1. When you execute `npm run` (or `npm run-script`), it looks for the executables installed locally first. This allows to use different versions for these executables for every project (for example, if some library is incompatible with new version of `tsc`). So, if `tsc` is installed as dependency (or dev dependency), `npm run` will execute it, not the one installed globally. The same holds with `gulp` and other CLI tools.
2. `npm run-script` is not a package, it's an internal `npm` command, just like `install` and others. You can check this with `npm help` - this command shows the list of all built-in commands at once.